# Updating production server from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: updates

I have an older server that's running 13.10, I want to update it to the LTS version.

Will a simple `do-release-upgrade` do the job, or do I need to tell it to update specifically to 14.04 instead of the current newest version?

Comment: My main question is whether it will update to 14.04, or whether it will want to go to the newest version - do you know?

Comment: I think it gives you the option.